# How to define variables in if statements and use them outside of that statement?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

```
if (difficulty.equals("easy")) {
    System.out.println("Setting stats to " + difficulty);
    int food = 3000;
    int foodperson = 5;
    int energy = 0;
    int hulltotal = 5000;
    int hullhealth = 5000;
    int enemy1basehealth = 10;
    int enemy1basedamage = 1;
    int daystillevents = 80;
}

System.out.println("food: " + food);
```

When you try to print the variable of food, then you get an error. How do would you make it so that when you try to print it, it will successfully print the correct information?

Comment: You can't. What if that `if` is not executed? What should the last `println` then print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define them outside of the if statement.

```
int food = 0;
int foodperson = 0;
int energy = 0;
int hulltotal = 0;
int hullhealth = 0;
int enemy1basehealth = 0;
int enemy1basedamage = 0;
int daystillevents = 0;

if(difficulty.equals("easy")){
    System.out.println("Setting stats to " + difficulty);
    food = 3000;
    foodperson = 5;
    energy = 0;
    hulltotal = 5000;
    hullhealth = 5000;
    enemy1basehealth = 10;
    enemy1basedamage = 1;
    daystillevents = 80;
}
System.out.println("food: " + food);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A variable is only available within the scope in which it's defined.

You do have a couple of options, however. You can print inside the if statement.

```
if(difficulty.equals("easy")){
    System.out.println("Setting stats to " + difficulty);
    int food = 3000;
    int foodperson = 5;
    int energy = 0;
    int hulltotal = 5000;
    int hullhealth = 5000;
    int enemy1basehealth = 10;
    int enemy1basedamage = 1;
    int daystillevents = 80;

    System.out.println("food: " + food);
}
```

Or you can define food outside of the if statement. This option is more flexible as you have access to food anywhere in the current scope, but if you don't need it elsewhere go with the first option. It's typically good practice to define your variables within the scope you need to use them.

```
int food = 0;

if(difficulty.equals("easy")){
    System.out.println("Setting stats to " + difficulty);
    food = 3000;
    int foodperson = 5;
    int energy = 0;
    int hulltotal = 5000;
    int hullhealth = 5000;
    int enemy1basehealth = 10;
    int enemy1basedamage = 1;
    int daystillevents = 80;
}
System.out.println("food: " + food);
```